# How to create multiple Debezium connectores for mysql database

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am tring to connect multiple Debezium connectores for a mysql database and my configurations are as follows.

```
sudo docker run -it --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:1.5  &

sudo docker run -it --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka:1.5 &

sudo docker run -it --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/connect:1.5 &

sudo docker run -it --name connect1 -p 8084:8084 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/connect:1.5 &
```

but when i tring to run second connector...following error occurred.

```
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: Please share more logs according to the internet the error message is just a symptom / last sentence and you should have more explicitly error messages beforehand

Comment: Have you tried changing GROUP_ID? also standard port for kafka-connect is 8083, so change second kafka-connect with this line `sudo docker run -it --name connect1 -p 8084:8083 -e GROUP_ID=2 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/connect:1.5 &`

Answer (score 1):

You're not running any connectors, only containers for workers.

One Kafka Connect worker can be used to submit more than one connector task via the HTTP server on port 8083

---

Regarding the commands shown, you do not need multiple containers unless you are trying to create a Connect worker cluster

In order to do so, they need the same topics and the same group id.

You'd also want `-p 8084:8083` since you've not changed the server port. Also, rather than using `&`, you can do `docker run -d`, but using Docker Compose would make more sense here

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for answering my question...tryig to create one connector task for one table...I tried that...it works but when im trying to use same configuration with different table...it won't work..

Comment: @SteaveJones please share your connector configurations in the question.

Comment: @SteaveJones I dont know where your mysql container is running, so 1) Docker cannot access host process, by default. If it is in another container, you need to also `--link` the mysql container 2) You haven't shown your connector configurations or any logs from the containers for us to really answer specific issues with a certain connector